# Weak convergence, together with convergence of norms, implies strong convergence in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a weakly convergent sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. If $\| x_n \| \to \| x \|$, show that $x_n$ converges strongly to $x$.

#### Context

This problem comes from a question in my exam paper; the original problem was incorrect.

Comment: So every sequence of unit vectors converges to every unit vector?

Comment: Clearly false. Easy to build a counterexample: let $v\in H$, $v\ne 0$, then take $X_n=(-1)^n v$.

Comment: Thank you TZakrevskiy, thats correct ! That was question in my exam paper.. and was incorrect.

Comment: I  edited the question into what it should have been, so that it can serve as a reference for this fact.

Comment: Does strong convergence implies convergence in norm?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The result you want to show should be: if $x_n$ converges to $x$ weakly and $\lVert x_n\rVert\to \lVert x\rVert$, then there is convergence in norm. To see that, expand $\lVert x_n-x\rVert^2$ and use the fact that $\langle x_n,x\rangle\to \lVert x\rVert^2$.

Comment: Thank you Davide Giraudo. Yes ! that is the correct version. but in my exam paper was wrong.

Comment: Does strong convergence implies convergence in norm?

Comment: @manhattan You mean convergence of the norms? Sure, by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Where is the completeness of the space $H$ used?

Comment: $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ is equivalent to [$\left\langle x_n, y \right\rangle \to \left\langle x, y\right\rangle$ for each $y \in H$] due to the Riesz Representation Theorem, (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weak_Convergence_in_Hilbert_Space) which doesn't apply to general inner product spaces and requires completeness. (I guess it's possible you might *define* weak convergence on Hilbert spaces this way too) For counterexamples of Riesz for non-complete $H$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678656/necessity-of-completeness-of-the-inner-product-space-in-riesz-representation-the.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo, this result still works for a reflexive space?

Comment: For extra information, we have $\langle x, x_n \rangle \to \langle x,x \rangle$ because of weak convergence and because $y \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle$  or $\langle y , x \rangle$ is a linear functional (depending on the convention) !