# Weak convergence under linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, weak-convergence

Consider the linear bounded operator $A:X\to Y$. Assume a sequence $x_n$ weakly converges to $x_0$ in $X$. It can be shown that the sequence $y_n:=Ax_n$ weakly converges to some element $y_0$ in $Y$.

Question: Under what conditions do we have $y_0=A x_0$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536101/weak-convergence-together-with-convergence-of-norms-implies-strong-convergence

Comment: @TsemoAristide How is that related to this problem?

Comment: Yes, and the proof follows easily from definitions: let $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$. Then $x^{*} = y^{*} A$ is in $X^{*}$ so $y^{*} (Ax_n)=x^{*}(x_n) \to x^{*}(x_0)=y^{*}(Ax_0)$.

Comment: I agree with Kavi. It is enough that $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, see Robert E. Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: please use the "answer" box for answers. The "comment" box is for comments.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy
Does this property also hold for a convex nonlinear operator?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if this is true for non-linear operators.