# Is there a sufficient condition such that the convergence of norms implies the convergence in norm?

Tags: geometry, limits, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

It is well known that under a certain condition (e.g. the weak convergence), the convergence of norms implying the convergence in norm, that means

> **Theorem.** (see e.g. [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536101/weak-convergence-together-with-convergence-of-norms-implies-strong-convergence#:%7E:text=company%20blog-,Weak%20convergence%2C%20together%20with%20convergence%20of%20norms%2C%20implies%20strong,convergence%20in%20a%20Hilbert%20space.&text=Let%20(xn)%20be%20a,n%20converges%20strongly%20to%20x.)) In a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, let $x_n$ be a sequence weakly converging to $x$. If $||x_n|| \rightarrow ||x||$  then $x_n$ converges to $x$ in norm, i.e. $||x_n-x||\rightarrow 0$.

I am wondering that **is there a similar result for [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional)?** (a.k.a. gauge function, block norm in combinatorics, atomic norm in signal processing).  I mean: is there a sufficient condition such that the following statement  holds true?

> **Statement.** For $x_n\in \mathcal H$, if $||x_n||_A \rightarrow ||x||_A$, then $||x_n-x||_A\rightarrow 0$.

Here $A$ is a closed convex set (not necessarily bounded) in $\mathcal H$ containing the origin as its interior point and $||\cdot||_A$ is the Minkowski functional corresponding to $A$, i.e. $||x||_A := \inf \{t\geq 0: x\in t A\}$ for all $x\in \mathcal H$.

Of course, this statement is not true even in $\mathcal H=\mathbb R^2$ if we don't impose any condition, indeed, see the counter example given in the following figure.

[image]

Is there any ideas?

Comment: As you said, it's not true without imposing a condition.  What condition are you imposing?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Yeah, the condition is what I am looking for.

Comment: Despite the name "weakly convergent to $x$" is still a fairly strong condition. It implies the *directions* to the $x_i$ converge to the *direction* for $x$. Then the convergence of the norms assures that the remaining freedom it had to diverge hadn't been exploited. You need the same thing for your functional. If the directions of the $x_i$ converge to the direction of $x$, convergence of the functional values should be sufficient to prove full convergence.

Comment: @Pau Not very clear for me! Do you mean: " If $x_n$ weakly converges to $x$ and $||x_n||_A\rightarrow ||x||_A$, then $||x_n-x||_A\rightarrow 0$? If such case holds true, could you please illustrate your arguments as an answer below?!

Comment: I didn't make an argument. I gave a suggestion on where you could look. $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ says only two things about $(x_n)$: that it is bounded, and that all of its limit points lie on a sphere of radius $\|x\|$ in the normed space. But those limit points could be scattered in every direction on that sphere. It is weak convergence that prevents this scattering of directions. You effectively have the same thing going on with a different norm. Even though the norm is not from the inner product, it is likely that weak convergence stills prevent scattering of directions here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah ok thank you so much! I got your idea! Intuitively, I think that your suggestion is applicable when $||\cdot||_A$ being a strictly convex norm. However, in the general case, I think that it is much more difficult.

Comment: You might have to modify the concept of weak convergence to provide what you need. Or else look for a different condition that will guarantee convergence of directions.

Comment: I found a useful result: Vincent Roulet, On the geometry of optimization problems and their structure, Prop 4.1.3. e-page 70/190.